# Google Apps script DateTime Format

Tags: google-apps-script

I need special Date format but I got error

Format what I need: yyyy-MM-dd’T’HH:mm:ss.SSSZ

**Examples of string I need:**

```
"2000-10-31T01:30:00.000-05:00"
"2018-10-23T13:10:10.825+03:00"
```

**My code:**

```
var datetime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

Error I got: Invalid argument: yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ (line 83, file "Code")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this Code. This will give you the expected Result

```
var datetime=new Date(now.getTime()).toISOString();
Logger.log(datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the oracle documentation [link in the google Apps script help](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)  , the format string to add Timezone as you want (`"2018-10-23T13:10:10.825+03:00"`) is:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to Stack Overflow! On how to format inline links and code blocks, see [the help centre's article on formatting](/help/formatting).