# Google Apps Script dateformat issue for ISO8601 timezone

Tags: google-apps-script, simpledateformat, date-format

I have to format date in a google Apps script but i have a mistake.

In the oracle documentation (link in the google Apps script help )[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html] , the format string to add Timezone is :

"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX" => 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235**-07:00**

When i use that format string with Google Apps script, the formated date is (without milliseconds) :

"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX" => 2022-06-05T22:00:00+0000 (the colon doesn't appear).

Is a bug or I doesn't have understand ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please show your code. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Apps script DateTime Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097699/google-apps-script-datetime-format)